# Binary String Lookup

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

is there a javascript script solution to inspect a string and based on the strings character position show a value. for instance:

0001001000010010

If the 1st bit is 1 then show red

If the 1st bit is 0 then show nothing

If the 2nd bit is 1 then show blue

If the 2nd bit is 0 then show nothing

And so on.

My string is currently just showing the 16 bit output

```
$("#spanwStatus_Word_1").text (Number(data[6]).toString(2));
```

Comment: Well, you _could_ do `if (str.charAt(0) == 0)` and so on, I guess. I don't think there is something that automates is any more than that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you describe details of _"And so on"_?

Comment: what do you mean show a value? show it somewhere in html?

Comment: Split the string using "" and loop over the resulting array using ternary

Comment: Hello, yes display a value in html. if bit 1 = 1 then <p>red</p>. if bit 1 = 0 then show nothing.

Comment: @BjH The last comment of yours is almost an answer to your question. What is the hard part of the task?

Comment: Hi @Teemu My lack of javascript knowledge. I'm very much a novice. I know what i need but am struggling to implement it.

Comment: @vlaz thank you for your suggestion. I used

var status = (Number(data[6]).toString(2));if (status.charAt(2) == 1)

Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
var res = words.filter ( (word, i) => num & (1<<i) );
```

```js
var words = ['indigo', 'grey',   'pink',  'red', 
             'blue',   'yellow', 'olive', 'beige',
             'green',  'orange', 'brown', 'fusha', 
             'purple', 'black',  'white', 'violet'],
    num = 0b0001001000010010;

var res = words.filter ( (word, i) => num & (1<<i) );

console.log(res);
```

You then have an array of words, one for every set bit.

Note that the words in the array are listed with the lowest index on the left, while (binary) numbers have the digit with the lowest "index" at the right. So if you set the least significant bit, you'll get the word at index 0.

If you need to have the blanks included in the array, then use `map`:

```
var res = words.map ( (word, i) => num & (1<<i) ? word : '' );
```

```js
var words = ['indigo', 'grey',   'pink',  'red', 
             'blue',   'yellow', 'olive', 'beige',
             'green',  'orange', 'brown', 'fusha', 
             'purple', 'black',  'white', 'violet'],
    num = 0b0001001000010010;

var res = words.map ( (word, i) => num & (1<<i) ? word : '' );

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @ trincot thank you for your reply. Being a novice i struggled to understand your code. thanks for your time though.

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I'd be happy to give it. Or have you grasped it in the mean time?